# Separating lines in mysql query

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a mysql database where several URL's are saved in one field (see below). I now need to separate those URL's to insert them in a new database where each URL has it's own ID/Row.

Unfortunately I only got so far to separate the first URL from the others with Substring and wasn't able to get the following ones.

Here an example for such a field:

```
www.1234.com
www.435346.com
www.35345567.org
www.9380.net
...etc.
```

so there can be different numbers of URL's in the field.

I can get the first one with:

```
INSERT INTO url (url)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(old_url_field, 'www', 2)
FROM old_table
```

But I have no real idea how to get all the others.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

The solution from PaparazzoKid worked with some changes for me.

I just had to make some changes, because the URL's in my case are not separated by spaces but by line breaks [CHAR(10)], but then it worked perfectly, you can find my solution here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b882/2

or as code directly below:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(80));

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES
(1, 'www.mysite.com
www.anothersite.com
www.siteone.com'),
(2, 'www.sitetwo.net');
```

My modified SQL code:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, CHAR(10), numbers.n), CHAR(10), -1) url
FROM
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) numbers INNER JOIN tablename
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name,CHAR(10), '  '))
     -CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  n
```

Comment: It might be easier to write a small script for it in a programming language. You can fetch the data from the old database, process it, and then insert it in the new one.

Comment: is this a one time effort? or will you need to keep doing it?

Comment: So you want to separate it into 3 parts? Can url be like `foo.bar.baz.or.whatever.com` ?

Comment: @Randy it's just a one time effort for migrating the old database to a new one.

Comment: @AlmaDo I simply want to have each URL (they all are formatted like www.something.tld) in one row/ a seperate "dataset" in the new database, so that I can link as many urls as I like "clean" to another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may get you heading in the right direction:

**Using this makeshift data:**

```
CREATE TABLE oldTable (
  id INT,
  url VARCHAR(80));

INSERT INTO oldTable VALUES
(1, 'www.mysite.com www.anothersite.com www.siteone.com'),
(2, 'www.sitetwo.net');

CREATE TABLE newTable (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  oldID INT,
  url VARCHAR(100));
```

**This query works:**

```
INSERT INTO newTable (oldID, url) 
    SELECT
      oldTable.id,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(oldTable.url, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1) url
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN oldTable
      ON CHAR_LENGTH(oldTable.url)
         -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(oldTable.url, ' ', ''))>=numbers.n-1
    ORDER BY
      id, n
```

**Result:**

```
SELECT * FROM newTable

id  | oldID | URL
----|-----------------------
1   | 1     | www.mysite.com
2   | 1     | www.anothersite.com
3   | 1     | www.siteone.com
4   | 2     | www.sitetwo.net
```

[See the SQLFIDDLE demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e481fb/1)

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked for me with some changes. In my case the URL's are not seperated by Spaces but by Line Breaks [CHAR(10)] so I had to modify some things as seen here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b882/2  I'll post the detailed solution (in case somebody else has a problem like this) later as a separate Answer.

Comment: @user3136758, don't post it as another answer, add it to the end of your question as a 'working example'. The changes you made weren't extreme enough to warrant a new answer. I think other users will know how to modify the script to split line-breaks, just like you did. I wrote that answer knowing that adjustments were needed to suit your case.